# how to use a bit type variable as precondition for a criteria in where clause in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a bit type variable `@ExcludeCB` which allows user to exclude a type of transactions from query result. The question is that how I can combine this condition `if @ExcludeCB = 1 then TN.TT !='CB'` to other conditions? I used the `CASE WHEN` but it reflected Error. Here is a part of the code:

```
declare @FVoucher as int; ---- first Accounting Voucher No

declare @LVoucher as int; ---- last Accounting Voucher No

declare @ExcludeCB as bit; ---- excluding Transaction type CB


set @FVoucher = 2004002;

set @LVoucher = 2004120;

set @ExcludeCB =1 


WITH ctOB as  ---- making a TB prior to the report range

( Select GLcode, GLname, Sum((case WHEN amount>0 then Amount ELSE 0 END)) as obDebit , 

    Sum((Case When Amount <0 then - Amount ELSe 0 END)) as obCredit

    From TN 

        WHERE Year(tn.GDate) = Convert(int,substring(Convert(varchar,@fVoucher),1,4)) and tn.VoucherNo < @FVoucher

        AND Case @ExcludeCB when 1 then tn.tt !='CB' ELSE 1 = 1 END

    group by GLcode, GLname

) ,
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make sure that all code is marked up as code, and all non-code isn't **shouting** at us.

Comment: Case sounds like the right approach; what's the error?

Comment: @Xedni - CASE doesn't sound like the right approach. This seems like a common (I'm not sure where it comes from) error of not just writing boolean logic. I.e. write the rest of the `WHERE` clause and then `AND (@ExcludeCB = 0 OR (<further conditions apply>))`.

Comment: sorry , it was my first time posting question, I mixed up with how to format it as code and and normal text. however I do not know how to correct it.

Comment: As general advice, in any new encounter with a new environment, you *ought* to try to learn the norms of that environment before posting anything to it. There's a *lot* you can learn by reading through the help section of this site.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever maybe I misunderstood the question. The code is a bit scrambled, so I was using a combination of the description and the existing code to assert it was a case statement hew as after.

Comment: @Xedni - people latch onto `CASE` and, more often than not with SQL, it's inappropriate. They're trying to apply a procedural approach when a set-based one is more appropriate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever fair point. However I'd still like to know the specific error the OP is getting.

Comment: @Xedni - I've seen this one more than just once or twice. They want to apply logic "only under certain conditions", i.e. exactly what is described by applying boolean logic if you think about it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your are trying to get two different conditions with the `CASE` statement, but you can't do that because all the parts of a `CASE` must return a value or NULL (something that you can use as a column value), and in SQL Server you don't have a boolean type for variables/columns.

SQL Server has the `bit` type which looks like a boolean but is different, because its possible values are `0`/`1`, nor `true`/`false`. With real boolean types you can use `if boolean_varible=true` or better `if boolean_variable` to get a boolean condition, but with a `bit` type you always have to use `if bit_variable=1`.

Returning to your question, in order to get what you want you can replace:

```
AND Case @ExcludeCB when 1 then tn.tt !='CB' ELSE 1 = 1 END
```

with something like this:

```
AND ((@ExcludeCB=1 and tn.tt !='CB') or @ExcludeCB=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is an expression rather than a statement in SQL Server. You'll need to include the CASE expression in a predicate for use in the WHERE clause. The method below uses the simple form of `CASE` instead of the searched `CASE` you were attempting:

```
AND CASE WHEN @ExcludeCB = 1 AND tn.tt <> 'CB' THEN 1 END = 1
```

The result of this `CASE` expression will be 1 when `@ExcludeCB` is 1 and `tn.tt` is not equal to 'CB'.  The CASE result will then be compared to the literal 1 in the predicate, resulting in a true `WHERE` clause condition. The `CASE` expression will otherwise return `NULL`, resulting in an unknown predicate because anything compared to `NULL` is unknown. No rows will then satisfy the condition because unknown is not true.

You could also use `OR` to express the condition without a `CASE` expression. This example considers the possibility of a `NULL` `@ExcludeCD` value:

```
AND (ISNULL(@ExcludeCB,0) = 0 OR (@ExcludeCB = 1 AND tn.tt <> 'CB'))
```

Comment: Dan - Neither of those options would allow a seek operation against t..tt (assuming the existence of an appropriate index). A better syntax would be AND (@ExcludeCB IS NULL OR @ExcludeCB = 0 OR (@ExcludeCB = 1 AND tn.tt <> 'CB')) OPTION(RECOMPILE);

Comment: @JasonA.Long, I wasn't thinking about a seek here since the index would unlikely be used due to the not equal operator, even with the alternative syntax and hint you suggested.

Comment: Yea, you're right. I was looking at the general code pattern. It would be interesting to see how the plan changes based on the ratio of CB to non-CB values in the colum.